# Small question on Pythagoras theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The projections-of-the-legs over the *hypotenuse* should add up to the *hypotenuse* $c$.
Is there any alternative way to prove below?
$$a\cos \alpha + b\sin \alpha = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, $$\cos \alpha = \frac ac\quad \&\quad \sin \alpha = \frac bc$$

so $$a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha = \frac 1c \times (a^2+b^2)=\frac {c^2}c=c$$

Of course, that last step requires the Pythagorean Theorem ("PT").  It is worth remarking that, without using PT the argument shows $$a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha = \frac {a^2+b^2}c$$ and since the OP has shown that $$a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha = c$$ we can combine the two arguments to get $$\frac {a^2+b^2}c=c \implies a^2+b^2=c^2$$ so the two arguments together yield a proof of PT.

Comment: Ahh how did I miss using the big outer triangle! Looks silly now haha thank you so much :)

Comment: @palaeomathematician that's right, but I can rearrange that step as below (next comment)

Comment: $$a*\cos \alpha +b*\sin \alpha = a*\frac{a}{c} + b*\frac{b}{c} = \frac 1c \times (a^2+b^2)$$

Comment: Then set that equal to $c$  : 

$$ \frac 1c \times (a^2+b^2) = c \implies a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Comment: Does that still feel like circular proof @palaeomathematician

Comment: @palaeomathematician I'm not sure I understand where the controversy is, or if there is controversy.  
   What I wrote is not a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem,, nor was it intended to be; indeed it uses that Theorem. Of course, the argument provided by the OP is also not a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem.  That argument does show that $a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha =c$ but the OP then uses the PT to get to $\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @lulu I think the OP wants to prove the Pythagorean theorem using that $a\cos \alpha + b\sin \alpha = c$

Comment: @palaeomathematician  Why do you think that?  The way I read the question, the OP was asking for a proof of the given formula that doesn't rely on the addition of the new perpendicular.   In any event, I wasn't trying to prove the PT.

Comment: @palaeomathematician  Worth remarking, that without using PT my argument shows $a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha = \frac {a^2+b^2}c$ and since the OP's argument  shows that $a\cos \alpha +b\sin \alpha = c$ we can combine the two arguments to get a proof of PT.

Comment: @lulu By using elementary trigonometry the OP concluded that $a\cos \alpha + b\sin \alpha = c$. But he also knows that according to the PT we should have $c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So he wants to prove that $c = a\cos \alpha + b\sin \alpha  = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $, that is that the PT holds. But maybe we should wait to see what the OP says, since only he knows what he wanted.

Comment: You both are right. In the post I didn't mention it as a proof for PT because I was just looking for another connection between $a\cos \alpha + b\sin\alpha$ and $c$. Thanks again :)